# Share gha Docker cache among branches?

Tags: docker, github-actions, buildx

Is it possible for multiple branches in a github repo to share entries in the gha cache? I have a CI workflow in a github repo. This workflow builds a Docker image and pushes it to the gha cache using `build-push-action`. When I push commits to an existing branch/PR, `build-push-action` successfully loads the Docker image from the cache (good). However, when I push a new branch, CI builds the Docker image from scratch, then caches the image.

Since the Dockerfile is the same in both branches, I would like the second branch to load the original image from the cache rather than rebuilding it. It seems as if cache entries are keyed by branch name. How can I share cache entries among multiple branches?

Here is an example workflow file which demonstrates my issue:

```
name: My CI
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build Docker Image
    steps:
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          load: true
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
```

Comment: did you come to a solution in the end?

Comment: I don't think this is supported right now. By default, builds are [scoped to branch](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/cache/backends/gha/#scope). Github actions, however, [do support accessing cache of parent branch from child branch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#restrictions-for-accessing-a-cache). As this is not the default behaviour, you'll need to implement this yourself. You can follow the example in this [answer](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/225). You'll have to manage saving and loading cache.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things you can do here.

1. Only have one cache. This is very simple, just use:

   ```
   cache-from: type=gha,scope=global
   cache-to: type=gha,mode=max,scope=global
   ```

   It doesn't actually matter what the scope is, just that you've overridden it, so it no longer uses the default, which is (as you observed) the branch name. Then any branch build will use the same cache.

   The drawback of this approach is that your branch builds will overwrite your cache, so if you're developing on many branches concurrently, they'll tread on each other's toes. You'll still get caching of whatever layers they have in common, but your modifications from the branch will be inconsistently cached.
2. Have a cache for each branch, but also use the main branch cache as a fallback.

   The `--cache-from` option to the underlying command can be passed multiple times, and it'll just try all the caches. `cache-from` in the `build-push-action` also says in the docs that it's a list, but doesn't say how to specify multiple entries. In the end I read the code for the action to figure out how the option is parsed, and it seems that the answer is to separate each entry with newlines:

   ```
   cache-from: |
     type=gha
     type=gha,scope=main
   cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
   ```

   (assuming your default branch is called main).

   The main drawback of this approach is that when you merge your branch, your main build doesn't use the cache for your branch, just its own cache. Maybe there are ways you could fix this (e.g. try to dynamically figured out which branch was merged and add it to the list), but this solution is good enough for me. (I'm also not sure how cache entries for deleted branches get cleaned up, but that's a problem for another day.)